# Can I write abc.ABC without resorting to metaclasses in Python 3.6?

Tags: python, metaclass, abc

[Python 3.6](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html) added [PEP 487](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0487/), which adds an `__init_subclass__` method among other things.  Is it possible to write a version of [`ABC`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/abc.html#abc.ABC) that doesn't use a metaclass?

Comment: If all you care about is the check for abstract methods, then yes. But abcs also support [virtual subclass registration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yes, I meant to specify that all I care about is the check for abstract methods.

Comment: Is this about writing an alternative to the standard library `ABC`, or about how to use the existing `ABC`?

Comment: @HåkenLid An alternative.  The problem with metaclasses in Python is that as soon as I have more than one in my inheritance tree, I have to start composing the metaclasses, which is annoying.  However, I would like to use the abstractmethod functionality.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you care about is the check for abstract methods, then yes. Just move the [abstract method set computation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Lib/abc.py#L134-L143) to the `__init_subclass__` method:

```
def __init_subclass__(cls, **kwargs):
    super().__init_subclass__(**kwargs)
    # Compute set of abstract method names
    abstracts = {name
                 for name, value in vars(cls).items()
                 if getattr(value, "__isabstractmethod__", False)}
    for base in cls.__bases__:
        for name in getattr(base, "__abstractmethods__", set()):
            value = getattr(cls, name, None)
            if getattr(value, "__isabstractmethod__", False):
                abstracts.add(name)
    cls.__abstractmethods__ = frozenset(abstracts)
```

The base [`object.__new__` implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/v3.6.1/Objects/typeobject.c#L3476-L3519) then uses an non-empty `__abstractmethods__` set to prevent instantiation.

But ABCs also support [virtual subclass registration](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta.register); the [two hook methods this requires](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#customizing-instance-and-subclass-checks) **have** to be implemented on the metaclass.

Comment: How do I implement the check for abstract methods?

Comment: okay, and then can you block instantiation in `__new__` if there are leftover abstract methods without using a metaclass?

Comment: @NeilG: sorry, the base `object.__new__` implementation does this already.